# Followed the android tutorials to create an widget, but the widget is not showing up on my widget list

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm having trouble having a widget show up in my widget list, my code is similar to the one presented in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html, i'm not sure what i'd doing wrong.
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chibiclockwidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Clock"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <reciever
            android:name=".ClockProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </reciever>
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

widget_info:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/yami"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

widget_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetclock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I cant really find any errors in my code, can any one pick out whats wrong? Also, I'm testing on my S3 and using a different launcher, does that effect how I should be setting up the widget?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm...I'm having the same issue. I think what I'm missing is whatever triggers Android to categorize
an installed APK as a WIDGET vs just a normal APP. I say that, because, even after deploying and running my code,
it still always shows in the 'app' section of installed APKs
and not in the 'widgets' section. Does this help anyone come up with a theory/answer?

Comment: all looks good - you DO have that activity included in your test app right? Does the activity run properly?

Comment: try adding android:installLocation="internalOnly" below package="com.example.chibiclockwidget"